# Chrome driver compability issues on Raspberry PI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi

I have a Java program that was running without any issues before. The program uses Selenium to do a browser action. I did a fresh installation of Raspbian and now the program is not able to open Chrome. I already installed Java and the Web Driver.

Openjdk version "11.0.18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Raspbian-1deb11u1)
Chromium version 113.0.5672.95 running on Raspbian 11 32 bits

The error I am getting in the terminal when running my Java program is:
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and complete error stacktrace.